# Efficient way to round n to a multiple of m

Tags: optimization, math, rounding

Here's what I currently have:

```
function getNearestMultipleOf(n, m) {
    return Math.round(n/m) * m;
}
console.log(getNearestMultipleOf(37,18)); //36
```

A friend told me Math.round is expensive and a more efficient way is to use modulo to check if n has to be rounded up or down and use either `Math.ceil` or `floor`.

How would you do this?

Comment: From a codegolfing perspective, this looks pretty darn efficient already.  Since your users are probably downloading this script, a longer one could be significantly more "expensive" timewise by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: I might be doing the calculation server-side in PHP or something. Removed the javascript tag for clarity.

Comment: What language do you use? What are the types of n and m, integer (signed or unsigned?) or floating point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a bunch of ways:

```
<script>

// Math
var floor = Math.floor;
var time1 = +new Date();
var n = 586;
var m = 18;

// Math.round
for (var h=1.01, i = 5000000; i--;) {
   Math.round(n/m) * m;
}
console.log("Math.round:" + (+new Date() - time1));

// Math.ceil/floor
time1 = +new Date();
for (var h=1.01, i = 5000000; i--;) {
   if (n%m < m/2) {
        Math.floor(n/m) * m;
    } else {
        Math.ceil(n/m) * m;
    }
}
console.log("Math.floor/ceil:" + (+new Date() - time1));

// Shorter Math.ceil/floor
time1 = +new Date();
for (var h=1.01, i = 5000000; i--;) {
    Math[n%m < m/2 ? 'floor' : 'ceil'](n/m) * m;
}
console.log("Shorter Math.ceil/floor:" + (+new Date() - time1));

// Bitwise1
time1 = +new Date();
for (var h=1.01, i = 5000000; i--;) {
   if (n%m < m/2) {
        ~~(n/m) * m;
    } else {
        ~~(n/m + 1) * m;
    }
}
console.log("Bitwise1:" + (+new Date() - time1));

// Bitwise2
time1 = +new Date();
for (var h=1.01, i = 5000000; i--;) {
   ~~(n/m + 0.5) * m;
}
console.log("Bitwise2:" + (+new Date() - time1));

// lessOne/moreOne
time1 = +new Date();
for (var h=1.01, i = 5000000; i--;) {
    lessOne = n-(n%m);
    moreOne = lessOne + m;
    if((n-lessOne) < (moreOne - n)) {
        //lessOne;
    } else {
        //moreOne;
    }
}
console.log("lessOne/moreOne:" + (+new Date() - time1));

</script>
```

Result:

```
Math.round:188
Math.floor/ceil:215
Shorter Math.ceil/floor:381
Bitwise1:171
Bitwise2:135
lessOne/moreOne:120
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use **modular** operator and simple **substraction** ?
http://jsfiddle.net/LCDy6/1/

```
function getNearestMultipleOf(n, m) {
    lessOne = n-(n%m);
    moreOne = lessOne + m;
   if((n-lessOne) < (moreOne - n))
        return lessOne;
    else
        return moreOne;   
}
alert(getNearestMultipleOf(38,3));
```

Comment: The rounding is buggy. I'll post a case later.

Comment: sure. lets see how to make it flawless and efficient

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode:

```
let r = n modulo m;
let q = Math.Floor( n / m );  //div
if(r < m / 2.0) 
   answer = q*m;
else
   answer = (q+1)*m;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `(q+1)*m` to be a multiple of `m`?

Comment: @schnaader: Oops, typo :) Thanks, fixing

Comment: Took me a while to see that was pseudocode. One problem though, JS division isn't integral, so you'll need a `Math.floor` or `~~`.

Comment: As Box9 mentions: there is no integer division in JavaScript.

Comment: @Box: Oooh... sad :) OK then. Fixing that too

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach based on what you mention:

```
function getNearestMultipleOf(n, m) {
    if (n % m >= m / 2) {
        return Math.ceil(n/m) * m;
    }
    else {
        return Math.floor(n/m) * m;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, but you should probably verify the claim the Math.round is expensive before looking for an alternative.

```
function getNearestMultipleOf(n,m) { 
    return Math[n%m < m/2 ? 'floor' : 'ceil'](n/m) * m;
}
```